# Audio not triggered when specific images touch to other images

Tags: javascript, html, function, audio, konvajs

I am a non-native English speaker and I am a beginner of programming language. I understand that my explanation is not best but I am trying to explain better to people to understand what I am trying to do. So, please be patient with me and please not try to downvote (it hurt my feelings) instead of telling me why my explanation is bad. I appreciate your time to read this. Thank you.

I am working on a canvas game called coin sorting game which is dragging the coins to the correct piggy bank images and it will make the correct and the wrong sound when the coin touches correct image or not. 
I am stuck with if condition right now.

In the current state, a correct sound will play when the specific coin image touches the specific piggy bank image. However, the wrong sound also plays when any coin images touch to any piggy bank images. I am struggling to define else condition for this problem.

I tried to set the wrong audio function in else condition but the wrong sounds will play when any coin images moving and touch to the piggy bank images.

```
               playYesAudio();
           }else{
               playNoAudio();
      }
```

This is the HTML code...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.5/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/style.css"
</head>


<body>
    <div id="stage-parent">
    <div id="container">     
    </div>
</div>

        <audio id="yesAudio" >
        <source src="Audio/yes.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
        <audio id="noAudio" >
        <source src="Audio/no.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>


<script src="JS/moneysort.js"
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS code...

```
  var stageWidth =  1000;
 var stageHeight =  800;

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        width: stageWidth,
        height: stageHeight,
        container: 'container'
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    //1yen
    var ichiYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:20,
        y:20,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name: '1yen'
            }); 
    layer.add(ichiYenImg);

    //5yen
    var goYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:250,
        y:20,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name: '5yen'
    });
layer.add(goYenImg);

    //10yen
    var jyuYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:250,
        y:150,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name: '10yen'
    });
layer.add(jyuYenImg);

    //50yen
    var gojyuYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:20,
        y:150,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name: '50yen'
    });
layer.add(gojyuYenImg);

    //500yen
    var gohyakuYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:130,
        y:20,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name:'500yen'
    });
layer.add(gohyakuYenImg);

    //100yen
    var hyakuYenImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:130,
        y:150,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: true,
        name: '100yen'
    });
layer.add(hyakuYenImg);

  //piggy bank 1yen
  var ichiYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:100,
        y:500,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '1yen'
    });
layer.add(ichiYenpiggyImg);

//piggy bank 5yen
var goYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:450,
        y:500,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '5yen'
    });
layer.add(goYenpiggyImg);

//piggy bank 10yen
var jyuYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:800,
        y:500,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '10yen'
    });
layer.add(jyuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy bank 50yen
var gojyuYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:100,
        y:650,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '50yen'
    });
layer.add(gojyuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy bank 100yen
var hyakuYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:450,
        y:650,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '100yen'
    });
layer.add(hyakuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy bank 500yen
var gohyakuYenpiggyImg = new Konva.Image({
        x:800,
        y:650,
        width:100,
        height: 100,
        draggable: false,
        name: '500yen'
    });
layer.add(gohyakuYenpiggyImg);

//1yen
var imageObj1 = new Image();
imageObj1.onload = function(){
    ichiYenImg.image(imageObj1);
    layer.draw();
};
var sourceImg1 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane5.png";
drawImage(sourceImg1, ichiYenImg);

//5yen
var sourceImg2 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane6.png";
drawImage(sourceImg2, goYenImg);

//10yen
var sourceImg3 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane7.png";
drawImage(sourceImg3, jyuYenImg);

//50yen
var sourceImg4 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain02-money04.png";
drawImage(sourceImg4, gojyuYenImg);

//100yen
var sourceImg5 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain09-okane8.png";
drawImage(sourceImg5, hyakuYenImg);

//500yen
var sourceImg6 = "https://illustrain.com/img/work/2016/illustrain02-money06.png";
drawImage(sourceImg6, gohyakuYenImg);

//piggy1yen
var sourceImg7 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416628-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-96e8-e709ace70ec1.png";
drawImage(sourceImg7, ichiYenpiggyImg);

//piggy5yen
var sourceImg8 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416629-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-94a8-eb6c008d4584.png";
drawImage(sourceImg8, goYenpiggyImg);

//piggy10yen
var sourceImg9 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416630-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-95ef-a04228fc3c0d.png";
drawImage(sourceImg9, jyuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy50yen
var sourceImg10 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416631-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-9e99-43061e2eaf2c.png";
drawImage(sourceImg10, gojyuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy100yen
var sourceImg11 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416626-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-9ff6-00b3babf3fe9.png";
drawImage(sourceImg11, hyakuYenpiggyImg);

//piggy500yen
var sourceImg12 = "https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31402838/63416627-a322b080-c3b4-11e9-86c4-4edf13a57063.png";
drawImage(sourceImg12, gohyakuYenpiggyImg);

// This will draw the image on the canvas.
function drawImage(source, konvaImage) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = source;
    image.onload = function() {
        konvaImage.image(image);
        layer.draw();
    }
}

//use event delegation to update pointer style

layer.on('mouseover', function(evt){
    var shape = evt.target;
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    shape.strokeEnabled(false);
    layer.draw();
});

layer.on('mouseout', function(evt){
    var shape = evt.target;
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    shape.strokeEnabled(false);
    layer.draw();
});

//collistion
layer.on('dragmove', function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    var targetRect = e.target.getClientRect();
    layer.children.each(function(obj){
        if(obj === target){
            return;
        }
      // capture the result of the intersection test
      var checkHit = haveIntersection(obj.getClientRect(), targetRect);

      //get the objects name attribute
      var nameDragged1 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy1 = obj.attrs.name;
      var nameDragged5 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy5 = obj.attrs.name;
      var nameDragged500 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy500 = obj.attrs.name;
      var nameDragged10 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy10 = obj.attrs.name;
      var nameDragged100 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy100 = obj.attrs.name;
      var nameDragged50 = e.target.attrs.name;
      var namePiggy50 = obj.attrs.name;

      //decide if they match
      var checkNames = (nameDragged1 === namePiggy1 && nameDragged5 === namePiggy5&& nameDragged500 === namePiggy500 && nameDragged10 === namePiggy10 && nameDragged100 === namePiggy100 && nameDragged50 === namePiggy50 );


      //finaly decide if we have a valid hit
      if(checkHit && checkNames){
               playYesAudio();
           }else{
               playNoAudio();
      }

    });
});
function haveIntersection(r1, r2){
    return!(
        r2.x > r1.x + r1.width/2 ||
        r2.x + r2.width/2 < r1.x ||
        r2.y > r1.y + r1.height/2 ||
        r2.y + r2.height/2 < r1.y
    );
}

var y = document.getElementById("yesAudio");
function playYesAudio() { 
 y.play(); 
} 

var x = document.getElementById("noAudio");
function playNoAudio() { 
 x.play(); 
} 
/*
function fitStageIntoParentContainer(){
    var container = document.querySelector('#stage-parent');


    var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
    var scale = containerWidth / stageWidth;

    stage.width(stageWidth * scale);
    stage.height(stageHeight * scale);
    stage.scale({x:scale, y: scale});
    stage.draw(); 
}
fitStageIntoParentContainer();
window.addEventListener('resize', fitStageIntoParentContainer);
*/
```

Do I need to create a loop to else condition to select all the piggy bank images except the correct one to play the wrong sound audio?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In your current code. dragging the coin to the correct piggy. `playYesAudio() and playNoAudio()` run. And dragging the coin to the wrong piggy `playNoAudio()` only run ?

Comment: See refactored code at https://codepen.io/JEE42/pen/NWKQByV?editors=0010  An observation since you are new to coding - your approach to loading the coin and bank objects is not DRY (Do Not Repeat yourself]. Since they all have the same operation but have different images, they should be configured as data. This would allow you to extend the number of coins and banks, change the images, etc, without changing the code. This is the basis of writing larger programs - recognise patterns in your code and refactor anything that appears repetitive.

Comment: @DarkKnight, thank you for your response. My problem is playNoAudio() is making a sound when the coins collide to any images regardless of correct one or wrong one.

Comment: @VanquishedWombat, thank you for your suggestion! I knew I was repeating the same things and I wanted to reduce my code but I did not know-how. This is a very helpful tip! I am so lucky that you spent time to showed me this. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition for checking if a sound should play, and which sound should be played is not quite right.

Your first condition `checkHit` determines if the coin has intersected with a piggy bank. The condition `checkNames` determines which sound should play. However, you evaluate both, and if either one is false you play the "no" audio. So the "no" audio will play even when there was no intersection. You should only be playing any sound if they intersect, then deciding which to play.

```
// finaly decide if we have a valid hit
if(checkHit) {
    // Decide if it's the right coin + piggy bank
    if (checkNames) {
        playYesAudio();
    } else {
        playNoAudio();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I understand why I did wrong. I tried the code you suggested but still playNoAudio play when the coins touch to other coins or any piggy banks. Is this because checkHit determine collision with coins-coins, coins-piggy banks, piggy banks - piggy banks and coins and the piggy banks?

Comment: @Kijimu7 - it may be a coin-coin clash as you suggest, In the refactored code you can see that I added the objType=coin or piggy and included a check for this in the collision check. Before I did that I noticed that the coin-coin caused a false positive on the collision check.

Comment: @Vanquished Wombat, the playNoAudio(); is still playing when the coins are moving in x and y positions.  The amount of code is reduced and looks cleaner now.  Thanks again. I have a question, how can I set draggable: false for only the piggy bank images?

Comment: @Kijimu7 I've added another CodePen here based on that by @Vanquished Wombat: https://codepen.io/Daekard/pen/NWWKWMm. You can make only the coins draggable by adding another parameter to the `makeObject` function, and pasiing in whether `type=='coin'`, and setting the `draggable` property of the image. I've also updated the collision condition check so it should only play sound when there is a collision, and it is between a coin and a piggy bank.

Comment: Finally, it works as I hoped! @Daekard, and Vanquished Wombat, thank you so much for your explanation and for giving me your time to figure out find the solution. I learned a lot from this project when you guys are helping me to explain and how to solve the problems. I need to brush up my JavaScript knowledge. You guys are awesome :)